# Meteor: Add Bootstrap CDN links before admin dashboard route

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, materialize

`enter code here`I am using **`materializecss`** for UI of my app. I want to add admin package as well and for that i am using [yogiben:admin](https://atmospherejs.com/yogiben/admin) package. Problem is that to use this admin package i have to install `Bootstrap` packae as well which i can't do because i am using `materializecss` for UI work.

Now there is a little hack which i am trying to do, which is to add Bootstrap CDN links before **`/admin`** route.

Can someone help me how to add links to bootstrap cdn on fly. So when user logged in as admin and go to `/admin` route or `/admin/*` then bootstrap css and javascript should be loaded.

I am trying something like this:

```
Router.route("admin", {
path: AdminDashboard.path('/admin'),
  onBeforeAction: function(){
    link: {
      stylesheet: "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    }
    this.next();
  }  
});
```

But above code gives error

> Error: A route for the path "/admin" already exists by the name of "admin".

Comment: This might help http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/use-meteor-iron-router-waiton-to-load-external-javascript

Comment: Have you already written any code? It might help understanding your need and exact issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. I managed to do it myself. Here is solution if someone else looking for it.

```
    Router.onAfterAction(function(){
      var routeName = Router.current().route.getName();
      if ( routeName.indexOf("adminDashboard") == 0 ) {
        $("head #injectedBootstrap").remove(); //removes duplicates
        $("head").append($("<link rel='stylesheet' id='injectedBootstrap' href='/css/bootstrap.min.css' type='text/css' media='screen' />"));
        $("head #injectedBootstrapJs").remove(); //removes duplicates
        $("head").append($("<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>"));
      }
    });
```